# Transmission 2.76 compiling for PowerPC

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, open-source, powerpc, transmission

Transmission no longer has pre-compiled PowerPC support, but they still have source code available. I tried compiling it myself but got an error saying "The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old..." Anybody know how I could compile this? Or of a pre-compiled version somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install pkg-config first, which is apparently a dependency of Transmission.